# itemAdded in Tags Input Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, bootstrap-tags-input

I try to do something after a tag was added into input box, I know there are event in Tags Input Bootstrap called itemAdded. But I don't why, but my code is not working.

HTML:

```
`<input id = "zipcode" method ="post" type="text" class = "m-wrap tags" />`
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tags').tagsInput({
            'width': 'auto',
            'defaultText': 'e.g. 48108'
  });
});

  $('#zipcode').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
      // do something with event.item at here. example:
      alert(event.item);
  });

</script>
```

Don't know why this is not working. When I input new tag, nothing happen.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use change, blur, or mouseleave events? You also might want to double check your HTML. It might be formatted incorrectly. I.E. Extra spaces between the id and class attributes.

```
<input id="zipcode" method ="post" type="text" class="m-wrap tags" />
```